# Using multiple toggles I'would like to regroup all toggles in one action

Tags: ios, swift, toggle

I'm trying to create an array composed of multiple tools.
The array changes depending on which tools are carried.
Expecting a long list of tools I would like to avoid having to write an action for each single element to add or remove from the array. ( I managed this part as you'll see below)

Instead I'd like to use the name of the toggle switch and apply the same action to all the toggles on the screen.

I came up with this inelegant method:

```
import UIKit

class mainVC: UIViewController {
    
    
    var myEquippement: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        }

    
    
    @IBAction func shovelSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
                
        if sender.isOn{
            myEquippement.append("Shovel")
        }
        else {
            let subjectIndex = myEquippement.firstIndex(of: "Shovel")
            myEquippement.remove(at: subjectIndex!)
        }
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func hammerSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        
        if sender.isOn{
            myEquippement.append("Hammer")
        }
        else {
            let subjectIndex = myEquippement.firstIndex(of: "Hammer")
            myEquippement.remove(at: subjectIndex!)
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func screwdriverSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn{
            myEquippement.append("Screwdriver")
        }
        else {
            let subjectIndex = myEquippement.firstIndex(of: "Screwdriver")
            myEquippement.remove(at: subjectIndex!)
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func sawSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn{
            myEquippement.append("Saw")
        }
        else {
            let subjectIndex = myEquippement.firstIndex(of: "Saw")
            myEquippement.remove(at: subjectIndex!)
        }
    }
}
```

could you point me please to a better way of doing it.

I thought of using something like this:

```
@IBAction func toggleSwitched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn{
            myEquippement.append(sender.title!)
        }
        else {
            
            let subjectIndex = myEquippement.firstIndex(of: sender.title!)
            myEquippement.remove(at: subjectIndex!)
            
        }
        
    }
```

but `sender.title` always returns a nil value, the force unwrapping crashes the app.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: FYI - if you look at the documentation for [`UISwitch title`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch/3621876-title?language=objc) you will see it is only available when used under macOS.

Comment: You could have `let allEquipments: [String] = ["Saw", "Screwdriver", etc]`, have a `tag` on each switch which would be the index of the element in `allEquipments`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to have a master array of tool names. When creating a switch, assign its `tag` property to the corresponding index within that array.

Then in your single switch handler you can use the sender's `tag` to get the name of the tool from the master list of tool names. That will give you the title for the switch. Then your logic for adding/removing the title from `myEquipment` can be used.

Comment: Brilliant solution, thanks a lot. The `tag` assignment in `View` must start at 0.  ```@IBAction func toggleSwitched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
  
        let switchName = (masterArray[sender.tag])
        
        if sender.isOn{
            myEquippement.append(switchName)
        }
        else {
            
            let subjectIndex = myEquippement.firstIndex(of: switchName)
            myEquippement.remove(at: subjectIndex!)
            
        }```that's the final code I'm using. I put it here for any one who wants to see it applied.